# How can I debug open for cursor statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, debugging

I'm wondering  if it possible to debug similar statements in an easy way.
When I save the 'select string' in a variable , it become 'long' and I would need to split it in more variables.  I' presenting the very simplified sample:

```
OPEN o_recordset FOR
    'SELECT distinct
      a, b, c
  FROM t1,t2

  WHERE'
     || CASE  
     WHEN i_use_ctr_id = 1  then ' a = b' 
   END
   || ' ORDER BY 1 ASC  , DECODE('''||i_sort_order||''',null, '''', ''a'', '' NULLS LAST '',  ''b'' ,'',2 ASC NULLS LAST'')' 
   ;
```

I wish to see the select like this (i_use_ctr_id = 1, i_sort_order = a)

```
  SELECT distinct
      a, b, c
  FROM t1,t2

  WHERE a = b 
   END
  ORDER BY 1 ASC  , DECODE('a',null, '''', ''a'', '' NULLS LAST '',  ''b'' ,'',2 ASC NULLS LAST'')' 
   ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a debug procedure that either writes to a file or inserts in a table (with an autonomous transaction).

For instance:

```
CREATE TABLE debug_t (ts timestamp default systimestamp, data VARCHAR2(4000));
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE debug_p (p VARCHAR2) IS
   PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;
BEGIN
   -- you should split p if length is > 4000
   INSERT INTO debug_t (data) VALUES (p);
   COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Then you can debug values by inserting a single line of code:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_sql VARCHAR2(4000);
  3     i_use_ctr_id NUMBER;
  4     i_sort_order NUMBER;
  5  BEGIN
  6      l_sql := 'SELECT distinct
  7        a, b, c
  8    FROM t1,t2
  9  
 10    WHERE'
 11       || CASE
 12       WHEN i_use_ctr_id = 1  then ' a = b'
 13     END
 14     || ' ORDER BY 1 ASC  , DECODE('''||i_sort_order
 15     ||''',null, '''', ''a'', '' NULLS LAST '',  ''b'' ,'',2 ASC NULLS LAST'')'
 16     ;
 17     debug_p(l_sql); -- debug before opening cursor
 18  END;
 19  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> select * from debug_t;

TS                DATA
----------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11/09/13 11:52:30 SELECT distinct
                        a, b, c
                    FROM t1,t2

                    WHERE ORDER BY 1 ASC  , DECODE('',null, '', 'a', ' NULLS LAST ',  'b' ,',2 ASC
```